# Run-time Error '1004' for Excel VBA tables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running Excel 365 and getting the following error when trying to run a macro that inserts rows into tables.

> Run-time error '1004': This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.

I am trying to create a macro that would add rows to multiple tables. I'm using this to add a row before a total row:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
```

I think the problem is that it returns that error because the addition of a row in table1 affects table2 and it can't insert a row there. Ultimately I want table 2 (and other tables) to have a row inserted so I've tried:

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
```

But still returns the same error. I've tried reversing the order (adding to Table2 first) which executes the first command but then adding the row to table1 still returns the same error.

How do I add rows to multiple tables simultaneously?

The tables are stacked vertically, not side-by-side.

[speadsheet with tables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv6Mu.jpg)

Comment: What is the positioning of your tables - side-by-side or on top of each other? Is either filtered? Maybe a screenshot would help here.

Comment: I tried the first code in Excel 2013 and it worked, with onde table bellow and one by it's side. Maybe is a problem only with Office 365?

Comment: Without seeing your workbook, I suspect you've already figured out the answer; `...problem is...the addition of a row in table1 affects table2...`.  You'll have to insert cells instead of rows.

Comment: @ashleedawg I tried the code and it adds cells and not rows. As I stated in my comment, it worked with two tables surrounding it.

Comment: Edited original post. The tables are on top of each other. Screenshot attached. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when the higher table has a footprint that is either narrower than the lower table, or the same size but not exactly aligned. What happens under the covers when you insert rows into a Table is that Excel not only moves the table rows at the insert point down but also tries to insert cells *under* the Table in order to move anything directly underneath the Table down by the same amount of rows so that space between the bottom of the Table and any content sitting below it is preserved.

If you have another Table under that top Table that is either larger than the top Table or the same size but offset by some amount of columns, Excel tries to insert rows below the 'footprint' of the Top Table, but finds it can't do this, because this would move only some of the columns of the bottom table down, but not the others.

You can see this behaviour in the following images.

Here, I've got a Table and some non-table content below it:

[image]

Watch what happens when I insert a new row into the Table:

[image]

Excel did it without complaining, but as you can see, only the cells immediately below the top table got moved downwards.

Now, if I had a second Table under the first instead, I can't do this, because you simply can't shift *some* of the columns of a Table down a row while leaving the remainder in the old row. Indeed, here's the error message I get when I try:

[image]

Some ways to program around this include:

- Switch the position of the Tables
- Amend your code to temporarily move the lower table somewhere else,
  do the insert on the higher table, and then move it back again.
- Insert an entire row in the sheet (which also inserts new rows in the
  Tables that get bisected)

Comment: Wouldn't he also have to temporarily remove the `Totals` row from the upper table?

Comment: Nope. Works fine for me regardless of totals row.

Comment: Thought I remembered something about the Totals row causing a problem when one tried to expand a table. Probably I was confusing that with something else.

Comment: Weird: Images aren't displaying. Why the heck not?

Comment: I see them here

Comment: Interesting: I don't on my work PC, but I do on my personal one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, it works by moving the lower table to the side and the moving it back after inserting a row. I am still tinkering with relative displacement of the table because if I keep executing the move-table and then move-back after inserting a row eventually table 1 will bleed into table 2. I also need to dig up the code I've seen to hide the macro actions so they're not visible as they're happening. However, my original issue is resolved-- thank you.